# Images only showing filepaths in ListView c#

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I have a list' 'imagearealist' which has a list of filepaths to images. Using a for each loop

```
     foreach (String item in imagearealist)
            {

                imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(item));
                listView1.Items.Add(item);                
                listView1.LargeImageList = imgs;
                count++;
            }
```

In the listView1 box all I get is the filepath names in the centre of the box and no images. The filepath names - 'item' can load an image into a picture box but not the listView1 box. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks Steve

Comment: What is `imgs` ?

Comment: @Farzin This is the name of ImageList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test this:

```
count = 0;
listView1.LargeImageList = imgs;
foreach (String item in imagearealist)
        {
            imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(item));
            listView1.Items.Add(item, count);                

            count++;
        }
```

Comment: Could it be that I need to convert the 'imagearealist' into an array?????

Comment: I tested this exactly and working. Have you set the view of `listView1`? You can add this line to my codes: `listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;` If the result is still negative maybe image addresses are not true.

Comment: I think that my problem was that I was expecting to have the images themselves in the listView rather than icons of them. The View.LargeIcon 
did the job as I had originally used 'Details' rather than 'LargeIcon'.  Many thanks to you both for your help .. :)

Comment: @SteveGalvin detail view has no image, just like windows explorer detail view. And the image you see is not icon it is the image itself, you can change the size of showing images by `imgs.ImageSize = new Size(50, 60);` .  And in this case view must be set to `LargeIcon` because you only set large image list for list view. `listView1.LargeImageList = imgs;`

Comment: And please do not forget to point the true answer(s) by accept/upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining the image list every itteration of the array.  Define it once outside of the foreach loop and then add to it as you load each image, then assign the complete image list to the listView

```
ImageList imgs = new ImageList();
foreach (String item in imagearealist)
{
    imgs.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(item));
    ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem(item, count++));
    listView1.Items.Add(newItem);                
}
listView1.LargeImageList = imgs;
```

MSDN reference here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tried this but no joy.. :(

Comment: @SteveGalvin Hmm, Have you tried putting a breakpoint after the imgs.Add and checking the content of the imgs object? perhaps the Bitmap.FromFile isn't actually returning a valid object? might be worth breaking out into it's own variable to aid testing.  There might be some error occuring there (not found, permission, etc)

Comment: I put a Message Box in the loop to show the 'item' string and it was valid no extra "s or such like. I have used the same path to load images into Picture Boxes so I cannot see why it should not work here???

Comment: Could it be that I need to use an array instead of a List to call the file paths... just a thought???

Comment: @SteveGalvin I don't think an array is going to make much difference, I'd double check that the load is working so you know for certain that the list is being populated correctly.

Comment: @SteveGalvin I have just looked at the MSDN example again and they have created columns to enable display of subitems, perhaps this is the issue? or have you enabled columns elsewhere in the code?

Comment: @SteveGalvin sorry I misread that (have removed from example) I no longer think Columns was the problem

Comment: @SteveGalvin I just attempted the code from the MSDN example and it worked.  What format are your images in? I used bitmaps.  Also have you escaped all slashes in your paths? so \\ instead of just \  ?

Comment: I have added a picture box in the loop using the 'item' argument and the image shows in the picture box OK. The list view still shows only the file paths etc so the 'item' argument is working. Is there anything I need to do in the properties box in the Form1.cs[Design]?

Comment: @SteveGalvin I *think* I have cracked it! When you are adding the Items to the LIstView you are using a simplified constructor of a ListViewItem taking the string as it's only param.  If however you create a ListViewItem and pass it the string and also the index number (count) it can then relate the two together.  This seems to work in my own test case here, and I have ammended my answer to reflect this.  Hope this helps